# How to retrieve Source Details of copied content from clipboard

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I am trying to retrieve meta data from the clipboard to keep track of the copy pasted contents  using Javascript. I have tried using clipboardData object for getting the data but other than the copied content and type of content I am unable to get any thing.

Is it possible to get any kind of meta data along with the copied content like Source URL if copied from webpage or File name if copied from PDF or DOC etc..

Comment: You cannot retrieve clipboard info, it would pose a security threat if the user would have copied vital information to the OS clipboard. The only thing you can do is control a virtual clipboard inside your webpage, maybe with some browsers access other windows/tabs in the same browser, but that would be tops you could achieve. In the past I once saw that this was possible in IE; `window.clipboardData.getData('Text')`, but I highly doubt that still works. And if so, shame on Microsoft..

Comment: I have tried in IE and Chrome it is possible to get the clipboard content in IE as you said we can use window.clipboardData.getData('Text'); to get the content and in chrome I used 
key = event.clipboardData.types[0];
val = event.clipboardData.getData(key); to get the data, but I was wondering if we are able to get the content, why not the source information.

Comment: Text is the basic placeholder for the clipboard. Referenced data is only captured when the application can accept it. But in case of sandboxing in all modern browsers you will likely not get what's behind the "Key" of the data. You can always try and see what the console tells about the data returned from the object `window.clipboardData`. Look if it has certain methods or prototype handles that might be able to access such. Your quest will likely be in vain. I hope you can prove me wrong tho :) An alternative might be to request the file by letting the user input it through a File Open popup.